# MatDialog Angular open component?

Tags: angular, angular8

There is dialog: `public dialog: MatDialog` and method open() that opens dialog:

```
this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, conf);
```

Description of `open()` is:

```
open<T, D = any, R = any>(componentOrTemplateRef: ComponentType<T> | TemplateRef<T>, config?: MatDialogConfig<D>): MatDialogRef<T, R>;
```

Does it mean I should pass first parameter as instance component?

Why in example we use `MyDialogComponent` instead new `MyDialogComponent()`? What if `MyDialogComponent` has dependency injection in constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the object dialog will create that object dynamically and he DI will inject an dependence for you

this component as example the `AService` will inject by the DI system

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
  providers: [AService]
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData , public AService:AService ) {
      console.log(AService)
    }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a6kuhp)